# Can you load WFS uncached in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-2.10

I think this might be a bug, but we've just installed QGIS 2.10 and the WFS seems to be working strangely. When you load a WFS which is not cached the system loads all the visible features as expected. However, when you pan or unzoom the map the system does not load any additional features.

Effectively you only get to see the uncached features that are loaded when you first make the request.

Has anyone else noticed this issue? It seems to be related to a QGIS bug

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11968

You can replicate the bug with the BGS WFS:

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?